# How to repair cable at the breaker box knock out hole?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm getting ready to replace the breaker panel in my condo and I found some scary damage in one of the cables coming into the box from the top, just at the knock out hole (see picture). The damage black wire seems to be almost gone. It looks like I would need to add a piece of wire to extend it to the breaker that is connected. what is the best way to do this? I should be able to do whatever is needed since I'll have the old breaker box off.

I've been living here for 18 years and that breaker (not AFCI/GFCI) has never tripped. I wonder if this happened before my time.

[image]

Comment: Is the white insulated wire in that sheath OK or has it melted as well?

Comment: This kind of damage would not be expected to trip a breaker. Somehow the insulation and the conductor got damaged, maybe when the outer sheath was cut.  One scenario is that this created a high resistance leading to heating at the point of damage. Alternatively, or additionally, it could have arced to ground.

Comment: It seems likely to me that it had even ignited into actual smoldering flame at some point due to the black residue deposited on the side of the blue cable retainer. The green corrosion of the damaged wire and on the adjacent safety ground wire leads one to wonder what chemical reactions were going on over time in this area.

Comment: @ Michael Karas: I don't know. I'm afraid to touch it until I'm ready to replace the panel.

Comment: What was on that circuit? I do hope you have shut off the breaker to that circuit as soon as you discovered this.

Comment: Is the breaker panel inside? Flush mounted or surface mounted? I would not wait until you change the panel, unless you can do without that circuit. Put in a box above the panel, or use the approved splice which does not require a box. Splice on another piece of cable to go into the panel.

Comment: @JimStewart -- it's a flushmounted interior panel

Comment: Is that a 14-2 or a 12-2 cable that has the faulty spot in it, @Rodo?

Comment: @ Michael Karas: Ok, you convinced me to kill the breaker. It was for the garage door opener and the lights (by washing machine) in the garage. I plug the opener with an extension to an outlet in the garage. The outlets did not lose power.

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel: I'm not sure about the size, but it is a 15A breaker. The thicker cable/wires next to the bad black one are for the A/C, 40A breaker.

Comment: The bad black wire is not damaged. It looks like it arc to ground somehow because it was touching it. I pulled the black wire away and it is ...well...scorched but not pitted. Its insulation is gone at that point though. Power for that breaker is now off.

Comment: Remove the burned insulation and examine the conductor. If the conductor  looks sound you might be able to put multiple layers of electrical tape on it and then use it as is. then when you replace the panel you can try to pull some more wire or you can put in a splice in a box or use the splice which doesn't require a box. In the case of a flush mount panel, is it allowed to have an access port above the panel. Otherwise how would one fish cable for new circuits?