# Can I install a junction box near the floor to extend cables to a relocated panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, junction

I'm  doing a complete renovation of a 1970s era condo kitchen. I'd like to remove a wall but the unit's breaker box is located on that wall. The feeder cables going into the box and circuits exiting the box have very little excess length to them.

For the individual circuits that's not much of a problem as I'm taking most of the unit down to studs so I can just rewire each circuit. I don't think I could easily pull new feeder cables into the unit from the floor or meter box.

My question is with regard to the two feeders coming into the box. Can I install a splice box with terminal strips on the back side of a cabinet or false wall, 2 feet off the floor and then run new feeders and maybe even circuit wires to a new breaker panel at a compliant location?

Comment: Or this? [How to extend short wires into new panel?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147084/how-to-extend-short-wires-into-new-panel)